# Get list of audio mp3 files and play them in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I'm trying to build an audio player that gets the mp3 files from an external source along with logic for Play, Stop, Next and Prev buttons but I haven't figured out how to do it.

http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/BT - Paul Van Dyk - Namistai.mp3"
http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/Stevie Wonder - Skeletons.mp3

And then with C#, I'm opening a UnityWebRequest for the URI, save it into an AudioClip variable and then to an AudioSource variable but I'm then finding issues with using the length property/saving into some sort of Audio clip array.

Here's my code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] musicClips;
    private int currentTrack;
    private AudioSource source;
    public List<string> externalAudio;

IEnumerator GetAudioClip()
{
    externalAudio.Add("http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/Stevie%20Wonder%20-%20Skeletons.mp3");
    externalAudio.Add("http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/York%20-%20On%20The%20Beach.mp3");
    externalAudio.Add("http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/BT%20-%20Paul%20Van%20Dyk%20-%20Namistai.mp3");
    externalAudio.Add("http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/S.O.S.%20BAND-JUST%20BE%20GOOD%20TO%20ME%20(SINGLE).mp3");
    externalAudio.Add("http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/Michael%20Jackson%20-%20Beat%20It%20(Official%20Video).mp3");
    
    Debug.Log("Hello World");
    Debug.Log(UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip("http://localhost:8383/Unity3d/Audio/Stevie%20Wonder%20-%20Skeletons.mp3", AudioType.MPEG));

    foreach (var audioClip in externalAudio)
    {
        Debug.Log(audioClip);

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(audioClip, AudioType.MPEG))
        {
            UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest();

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                musicClips = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
                source.clip = musicClips;
                Debug.Log("Audio is playing.");
            }
        }
    }
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    //PLAY MUSIC
    PlayMusic();        
}

public void PlayMusic()
{
    if (source.isPlaying)
    {
        return;
    }
    GetAudioClip();

    currentTrack--;
    if (currentTrack < 0)
    {
        currentTrack = 0;
    }
    StartCoroutine(WaitForMusicEnd());
}

IEnumerator WaitForMusicEnd()
{
    while (source.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    NextTitle();
}

public void NextTitle()
{
    source.Stop();
    currentTrack++;

    if (currentTrack > musicClips.Length - 1)
    {
        currentTrack = 0;
    }
    source.clip = musicClips[currentTrack];
    source.Play();

    //Show title

    StartCoroutine("WaitForMusicEnd");
}

public void PreviousTitle()
{
    source.Stop();
    currentTrack--;

    if (currentTrack < 0)
    {
        currentTrack = musicClips.Length - 1;
    }
    source.clip = musicClips[currentTrack];
    source.Play();

    //Show title

    StartCoroutine("WaitForMusicEnd");
}

public void StopMusic()
{
    StopCoroutine("WaitForMusicEnd");
    source.Stop();
}
}
```

How can I save the external audio into an AudioClip list and then use them on the play/stop functions logic?

Comment: `UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip` as the name says gets not an array but **one** single audioclip. You either use individual WebRequests for each file (you could e.g. first request only a list from the server which returns the array of URLs to use for each clip) or you use a different approach and request raw bytes, find a way to split them into the individual clips (e.g. prepend the byte length before each clip), write them all to the hard drive and load them from there via individual WebRequests (yes the work also for the local file system)

Comment: @derHugo thank you for the help. I'm still blocked with the whole concept of UnityWebRequests. I've updated my code to add each mp3 URL to a list of strings and then pass those to the GetAudioClip but I need another clue to have this working...not asking for complete code changes but help on the approach for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm now getting the hang of this step by step. Creating fields to directly use them in Unity as to not hardcode them on the code is the same concept I use on the platform I work with, just didn't had the knowledge that this could also be done with Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a little bit broad but here is what I would probably do.

- As said let your server provide a list of URLs for the downloads. This way you don't have to hardcode them into your client.
- So with the previous point, the first thing you do is one single normal GET request to receive that list of URLs, e.g. simply separated by `\n` (line breaks)

  So the first string message you receive could look like e.g.

  ```
  http://localhost:8383/Moonbeam%20Challenge/Audio/Stevie%20Wonder%20-%20Skeletons.mp3   
  http://localhost:8383/Moonbeam%20Challenge/Audio/York%20-%20On%20The%20Beach.mp3
  http://localhost:8383/Moonbeam%20Challenge/Audio/BT%20-%20Paul%20Van%20Dyk%20-%20Namistai.mp3
  http://localhost:8383/Moonbeam%20Challenge/Audio/S.O.S.%20BAND-JUST%20BE%20GOOD%20TO%20ME%20(SINGLE).mp3
  http://localhost:8383/Moonbeam%20Challenge/Audio/Michael%20Jackson%20-%20Beat%20It%20(Official%20Video).mp3
  ```
- This received list you [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_StringSplitOptions_) into the individual URLs

  ```c#
  var urls = urlList.Split('\n');
  ```
- For these you start your individual `GetAudioClip` requests.
- The results you store in an array/a list as elements. You don't assign the entire `musicClips`. I would rather use a

  ```c#
   List<AudioClip> musicClips = new List<AudioClip>();
  ```

  and then from your downloads do

  ```c#
   musicClips.Add(DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www));
  ```
- you also don't want to assign and play each downloaded clip to the AudioSource as soon as it is downloaded but rather wait until all of them are downloaded (or at least the first one, depending on your needs)

So this might look somewhat like

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using System.Linq;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;

    [Header("Settings")] 
    [SerializeField] private string baseURL;
    [SerializeField] private string[] externalAudio;
    [SerializeField] private bool autoStartPlayAfterDownloads = true;

    [Header("Debugging")] 
    [SerializeField] private List<AudioClip> musicClips = new List<AudioClip>();
    [SerializeField] private int currentTrack;
    [SerializeField] private bool isInitialized;

    private Coroutine currentPlayTrack;

    // Yes, if you make Start return IEnumerator then Units
    // automatically runs it as a Coroutine
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // block input from the outside until this controller is finished with the downloads
        isInitialized = false;

        if (!source) source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Here either use the approach with first receiving a list from the server
        yield return GetAudioClipsInfo();

        // OR if you already have the clip urls assigned via the Inspector use one of
        yield return GetAudioClipsSequencial();
        // OR
        yield return GetAudioClipsParallel();

        // allow to do things from this point on
        isInitialized = true;

        if(autoStartPlayAfterDownloads) PlayFirstTitle();
    }

    // This is the routine that downloads the URL list from the server
    // then it starts the individual downloads
    private IEnumerator GetAudioClipsInfo()
    {
        // Make the first request for receiving the list of URLs from the server
        // If not using this but already assigning the urls
        // via Inspector then simply directly use the "GetAudioClips" below
        using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(baseURL))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            switch (request.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError($"Could not get list of clips! Error: {request.error}", this);

                    yield break;
            }

            var urlList = request.downloadHandler.text;

            externalAudio = urlList.Split('\n');

            // Here you can either go for the sequencial downloads
            yield return GetAudioClipsSequencial();

            // OR run them all parallel
            yield return GetAudioClipsParallel();
        }
    }

    // This version starts one download at a time, waits until it is done
    // then starts the next 
    private IEnumerator GetAudioClipsSequencial()
    {
        musicClips.Clear();

        foreach (var url in externalAudio)
        {
            Debug.Log(url);

            using (var www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(url, AudioType.MPEG))
            {
                yield return www.SendWebRequest();

                switch (www.result)
                {
                    case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                    case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                    case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                        Debug.LogError($"Could not get clip from \"{url}\"! Error: {www.error}", this);

                        continue;
                }

                musicClips.Add(DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www));
            }
        }
    }

    // This version starts all downloads at once and waits until they are all done
    // probably faster than the sequencial version
    private IEnumerator GetAudioClipsParallel()
    {
        musicClips.Clear();
        var requests = new List<UnityWebRequest>();

        foreach (var url in externalAudio)
        {
            Debug.Log(url);

            var www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(url, AudioType.MPEG);

            // Start the request without waiting
            www.SendWebRequest();
            requests.Add(www);
        }

        // Wait for all requests to finish
        yield return new WaitWhile(() => requests.Any(r => !r.isDone));

        // Now examine and use all results
        foreach (var www in requests)
        {
            switch (www.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError($"Could not get clip from \"{www.url}\"! Error: {www.error}", this);

                    continue;
            }

            musicClips.Add(DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www));

            www.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void PlayFirstTitle()
    {
        if (!isInitialized) return;

        if (source.isPlaying) return;

        if (currentPlayTrack != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(currentPlayTrack);
        }

        currentPlayTrack = StartCoroutine(PlayTrack(0));
    }

    private IEnumerator PlayTrack(int index)
    {
        // Make sure the index is within the given clips range
        index = Mathf.Clamp(index, 0, musicClips.Count);

        // update the current track to make next and previous work
        currentTrack = index;

        // get clip by index
        var clip = musicClips[currentTrack];

        // Assign and play
        source.clip = clip;
        source.Play();

        // wait for clip end
        while (source.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        NextTitle();
    }

    public void NextTitle()
    {
        if (!isInitialized) return;

        if (currentPlayTrack != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(currentPlayTrack);
        }

        source.Stop();
        currentTrack = (currentTrack + 1) % musicClips.Count;

        currentPlayTrack = StartCoroutine(PlayTrack(currentTrack));
    }

    public void PreviousTitle()
    {
        if (!isInitialized) return;

        if (currentPlayTrack != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(currentPlayTrack);
        }

        source.Stop();
        currentTrack--;

        if (currentTrack < 0)
        {
            currentTrack = musicClips.Count - 1;
        }

        currentPlayTrack = StartCoroutine(PlayTrack(currentTrack));
    }

    public void StopMusic()
    {
        if (!isInitialized) return;

        if (currentPlayTrack != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(currentPlayTrack);
        }

        source.Stop();
    }
}
```